# Regex matching between curly brackets yields too many results

Tags: php, regex, match, curly-brackets

I have a bunch of text, for example:

```
foofoofooabcdefhjkldh389dn{pdf}images/1.pdf,100%,500{/pdf}hfnkjt8499duidjglkj
```

I'd like to extract the following:

```
{pdf}images/1.pdf,100%,500{/pdf}
```

So here's a regex I made:

```
#{pdf}(.*?){/pdf}#
```

When checking the results I get back:

```
Array
(
[0] => {pdf}images/1.pdf,100%,500{/pdf}
[1] => images/1.pdf,100%,500
)
```

I expected to only get the first item in the array, but instead there's two items.
I'm using PHP and for testing I use the following website: [PHP Regex Tester](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php)

How can I only obtain the `{pdf}...{/pdf}` text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your using a group in your regex. in your case the group is

```
(.*?)
```

This causes PHP to give you the full result *{PDF}sometext{/PDF}* and the sometext as found in the first group.

just try the following to get rid of the group:

```
#{pdf}.*?{/pdf}#
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a non capturing group, to ensure the central text doesn't show up as a backreference in the array, and use zero width assertions to ensure the `{pdf}` part isn't part of the match:

```
#(?<={pdf})(?:.*?)(?={/pdf})#
```

If you want to keep the `{pdf}` delimiters:

```
#{pdf}(?:.*?){/pdf}#
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have twor results.

The problem (it is not a problem though) here is that probably a function [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) is used. This function returns both the whole matching query, that is `{pdf}images/1.pdf,100%,500{/pdf}`, as well as the final result, that is `images/1.pdf,100%,500`.

So You only need to use the `$result[1]` for further parsing.